# PHP not detect input name after check bootstrap confirm delete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for show confirm delete message before send form data:

JS:

```
$('input[name="S1"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    var checked = $("input:checked").length;
    var action = $('select[name="todo"]');


    if (action.val() === "delete" && checked) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $('#confirm').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        })
            .one('click', '#delete', function (e) {
            $form.trigger('submit');
        });
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <form method="POST" role="form" action="#">
    <div class="row margin-bt-15">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <select name="todo" class="contentgroup">
          <option value="">choose</option>
          <option value="delete">delete</option>
          <option value="mark">mark</option>
          <option value="unmark">unmark</option>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="MTQzNjU3MDc3NjZPNXFKUmZWVlJWcE9ZNnd4VUZFbmRiSzMzSTZwMzRD">
        <input type="submit" value="ok" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="S1" />
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="check" value="4" />
</form>
</div>
<div id="confirm" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">delete</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger fa-lg flashitmap"></i> 
        <label>message</label>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>delete</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-sm">back</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Now in PHP file i check `$_POST` using `isset` like this :

```
if ($_POST['todo'] && isset($_POST['S1']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  echo 'true';
} else {
  echo 'false';
```

always in result I see: `false` and my php code not detect `isset($_POST['S1'])` for my input name. how do can fix this ?

**NOTE:** when i remove bootstrap delete confirm, my form worked true and detect input name  `isset($_POST['S1'])`. I think my problem with bootstrap confirm code.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/530j1hmp/2/

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])`. see what's really showing up at the server.

Comment: form shown above isn't closed properly ... closing panel body before form

Comment: @charlietfl: not work.

Answer (score 0):

Apart form the things mentionned in the comments, there are several other to consider revision in your code.

1. `$_POST['todo']` can be an empty string if the user has not selected an item, because there is `value=""`. In PHP and other languages an empty string evaluates to `false`. Do you want it like this ?
2. if you have data in the `$_POST` array, then there it's a good bet your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` equals '`POST`'
3. To the main point: `isset($_POST['S1'])` will always be `false`. The element with name `S1` is an `input` with type `submit`, and as such, it will be submitted **ONLY** if it is the submitter, ie only if it has been clicked. But with `e.preventDefault()`, you prevent that action, and the form is submitted through `$form.trigger('submit');`.

If you really need it, a solution could be to use a hidden field (`type="hidden"`).

For more about which elements get submitted or not, you have the main rule on [w3's site](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set). Two other well known elements aren't submitted : radio button and checkbox if they have checkedness == `false`.